# Jenkins Docker image, to use bind mounts or not?

Tags: docker, jenkins

I am reading through this bit of the Jenkins Docker README and there seems to be a section that contradicts itself from my current understanding.
https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/blob/master/README.md

It seems to me that is says to NOT use a bind mount, and then says that using a bind mount is highly recommended? I'm confused.

> **NOTE: Avoid using a bind mount from a folder on the host machine into /var/jenkins_home**, as this might result in file permission
>   issues (the user used inside the container might not have rights to
>   the folder on the host machine). If you really need to bind mount
>   jenkins_home, ensure that the directory on the host is accessible by
>   the jenkins user inside the container (jenkins user - uid 1000) or use
>   -u some_other_user parameter with docker run.
>
> docker run -d -v jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home -p 8080:8080 -p
>   50000:50000 jenkins/jenkins:lts this will run Jenkins in detached mode
>   with port forwarding and volume added. You can access logs with
>   command 'docker logs CONTAINER_ID' in order to check first login
>   token. ID of container will be returned from output of command above.
>
> #### Backing up data
>
> **If you bind mount in a volume - you can simply back up
>   that directory (which is jenkins_home) at any time.**
>
> **This is highly recommended**. Treat the jenkins_home directory as you would a database - in Docker you would generally put a database on
>   a volume.

Comment: While I don't have time to read the full doc and get all the context, the first seems to be talking about bind mounting a **folder** and the second is talking about bind mounting a **volume**.  My docker isn't that strong, but if I remember correctly, you can do a lot more by setting up and binding volumes than by binding folders directly to the host system.

Comment: I have dockerized my fair share of Jenkins instances. In the long run, it’s just not worth the headaches. Just wait until you realize your dockerized Jenkins needs access to `dockerd` on the host to build other images.